# Why an id selector with a hyphen (-) does not work with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Am new to javascript and only started out learning. Here I have a javascript which counts characters.

**Javascript**

```
function CheckFieldLength(fn,wn,rn,mc) {
  var len = fn.value.length;
  if (len > mc) {
    fn.value = fn.value.substring(0,mc);
    len = mc;
  }
  document.getElementById(wn).innerHTML = len;
  document.getElementById(rn).innerHTML = mc - len;
}
```

and the **HTML**

```
<textarea name="taMessage" id="taMessage" cols="40" rows="5" onkeyup="CheckFieldLength(taMessage, 'charcount', 'remaining', 20);" onkeydown="CheckFieldLength(taMessage, 'charcount', 'remaining', 20);" onmouseout="CheckFieldLength(taMessage, 'charcount', 'remaining', 20);"></textarea>
<br>
<small><span id="charcount">0</span> characters entered.   |   <span id="remaining">20</span> characters remaining.</small><br>
```

for some reason, this does not work on JsFiddle but it is working on my laptop or else i would have put up a fiddle too. But this is not my problem (though would love to know why).

**Problem:** The id of the textbox is `= taMessage` but if I change the id to `= ta-Message`, adding a hyphen, the scripts stops working. Replacing the above html script with the one below stops the javascript and the only difference is the hyphen. Why?

```
<textarea name="taMessage" id="ta-Message" cols="40" rows="5" onkeyup="CheckFieldLength(ta-Message, 'charcount', 'remaining', 20);" onkeydown="CheckFieldLength(ta-Message, 'charcount', 'remaining', 20);" onmouseout="CheckFieldLength(ta-Message, 'charcount', 'remaining', 20);"></textarea>
```

Comment: `ta-Message` isn't a string, so you're actually trying to get a variable named `ta` and *subtract* a variable named `Message` from it. The reason the first works is that your element is available by ID as a global variable, but IMO there are better ways to fetch an element.

Comment: You don't need to pass in the field's id. Just pass `this`, instead.

Comment: And FYI, it likely doesn't work in jsFiddle because you're using the default setting that wraps your code in an `onLoad` function, so `CheckFieldLength` isn't globally available. Click the `JavaScript` menu to change that.

Comment: @J.Titus, you mean, CheckFieldLength(this, 'charcount', 'remaining', 20);?

Comment: @XYZ, sorry I did what you said but doesn't work.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @squint, what is the solution if my id has a (-) in between. Thanks for the fiddle advice.

Comment: @J.Titus, it works but what if I'd want to use the id name with a hyphen?

Comment: You can still use the id with a hyphen, you'd just need to put quotes around it, like XYZ mentioned, then in your JavaScript, call `getElementById(fn)` instead of just `fn.value`. The id string does not have a `value` property.

Comment: Can you guys please use the answer field so that I accept too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Problem: The id of the textbox is = taMessage but if I change the id
>   to = ta-Message, adding a hyphen, the scripts stops working.

Because hyphens are not valid in variable names in Javascript.

Global keys are added to `window` object, when you do `onkeyup="CheckFieldLength(taMessage,...);"` the value `taMessage` is actually `window.taMessage` which can also be accessed as `window["taMessage"]`.

hypen`-` is valid as `id` but not a valid variable name in Javascript neither does it work with `.` notation to access keys. But hyphens are supported as `keys` of objects, so in your case the `key` is `fa-Message`. You can use bracket notation along with parent `window` to access hyphenated keys like this `window['ta-Message']`

```
onkeyup="CheckFieldLength(ta-Message, 'charcount', 'remaining', 20);//Wrong
onkeyup="CheckFieldLength(window.ta-Message, 'charcount', 'remaining', 20);//Wrong
onkeyup="CheckFieldLength(window['ta-Message'], 'charcount', 'remaining', 20);//works
```

```js
function log(node){
    console.log("node", node);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="hyphenated-id" onclick="log(window['hyphenated-id'])"></textarea>
```

As noted by other comments, using `this` is a better option in your scenario

```js
function log(node){
    console.log("node", node);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="hyphenated-id" onclick="log(this)"></textarea>
```

even better is to use [EventListeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to bind events.

Answer (score 1):

That situation may be `this` keyword would help better, like

```
<textarea name="taMessage" id="ta-Message" cols="40" rows="5" onkeyup="CheckFieldLength(this.id, 'charcount', 'remaining', 20);" onkeydown="CheckFieldLength(this.id, 'charcount', 'remaining', 20);" onmouseout="CheckFieldLength(this.id, 'charcount', 'remaining', 20);"></textarea>
```

You can pass `this.id` or `this.name` whatever attribute that you are using in HTML tag.

I hope this simple trick help you more.

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass spacial character in element id or name.
You can also use **this** to get current text box like this

```
onkeydown="CheckFieldLength(this, 'charcount', 'remaining', 20);"
```

You Can also pass id name as string and your function code like this

```
 function CheckFieldLength(fn,wn,rn,mc) { fn = window[fn];}
```

Its can find element by id